# VBA Computing the average

Tags: vba, excel

This is the problem, I need to get the average of participation, quizzes, seat work and exam. The answer should appear in "total". But also the computed percentage to the next cell. I s there a macro for this that will compute them at one run only?

[image]

THis is what I get in Recording Macro:

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*10%"
    Range("C2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C3"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("C2:C3").Select
End Sub
```

But its simple in one run for easy computing

Comment: why not just apply a formula to every cell?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you would be better off using an equation in Excel rather than a Macro.  If you put the formula: `"=(B2*(10/100))+(D2*(20/100))+(F2*(20/100))+(H2*(50/100))"` into cell J2, and copy it down it should give you a weighted average of the scores.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think you need or want VBA for this.

I would set it up with the total points and the scale at the top with the scores below. Then you can more easily change them as needed. In cell J4 enter this formula `=B4/$B$1*$B$2+D4/$D$1*$D$2+F4/$F$1*$F$2+H4/$H$1*$H$2` and copy down.

[image]

Calculated by this method:

[image]